# Multibyte character export from HBase to CSV producing bad data

Tags: csv, export, hbase

I used a template to export data from an HBase table into a CSV file, however I'm running into apparent encoding issues. The data was all stored using UTF-8 and there are multiple different character sets used (Russian, Chinese, Arabic, etc..)

Here's the main loop that is exporting the data.

```
for(HBaseCol column: columns) {

byte[] val = result.getValue(column.family.getBytes("UTF-8"), column.qualifier.getBytes("UTF-8"));

if (val != null) {

    //System.out.println(new String(val,"UTF-8"));
    values.add(new String(val,"UTF-8"));
} else {
    values.add("");
}
}
```

The data with System.out.println() results in ?????? while the data in the CSV file is jargon, with random characters, etc..

Any insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple actually. The CSV exporter I was using wasn't equipped to handle UTF-8. I ended up exporting the data to memory, then inserting it directly into MySQL.